# Django program gets stuck on get request, needs to be interrupted with Ctrl C to continue

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, server

I have tried everything I can possibly think of but I don't know what the solution is. I have a django application which running on my local network and receives requests from a react app. When the page loads tables (around 10 requests) the server seems to work quite well but randomly gets hung. When it gets hung it doesn't reach the view (the print statement doesnt run:

```
def f(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    print('Received GET request'))
    ...
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

and the moment I interrupt it a backlog of get requests like:

```
Received GET request  <WSGIRequest: GET '/api>
Received GET request  <WSGIRequest: GET '/api>
Received GET request  <WSGIRequest: GET '/api>
Received GET request  <WSGIRequest: GET '/api>
Received GET request  <WSGIRequest: GET '/api>
```

which print in one go and then all the remaing requests are filled. Sometimes the requests with large responses crash, but sometimes even '/' hangs which only returns a hello world for me to test the server

I am using a conda environment with some:

```
asgiref                   3.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
django                    4.2.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
django-cors-headers       4.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
django-silk               5.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
djangorestframework       3.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
memory_profiler           0.58.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310h2cd9be0_0
pip                       23.3.1          py310haa95532_0
pyodbc                    4.0.39          py310hd77b12b_0
python                    3.10.13              he1021f5_0
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
sqlparse                  0.4.4           py310haa95532_0
```

I am also using a custom pyodbc sql class instead of the inbuilt django SQL model if that is important.

I tried to use Daphne + IIS + Django but the multiple threads were causing asyncio to throw errors which I wasn't able to solve:
`WARNING Executing <TimerHandle cancelled when=425584.421 AsyncioSelectorReactor._onTimer() created at C:\Users\adm-risk\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\risk-django-server\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py:281> took 0.109 seconds`

I switched to nginx + development server (to test for now and find the root cause) on Windows and moved back to wsgi standard (not asgi).

I used `memory_profiler` to identify any memory leaks but either there are none or the app freezes before it can output a proper result. I also used silk but it didn't help.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, not sure where to begin and the Windows environment is not helping

Comment: A request expects a response. Your view doesn't return one.

Comment: @Niko that was just to show the first line of my view, I've edited the post. All my views are returning a response,